# Why is my prolog predicate stop when it gets the first answer?

Tags: prolog, chatbot

I have this predicate:

```
ans(["Hello"],0).
ans(["Hello", "dear", "customer"],0).
ans(["Good","Morning"],0).
ans(["Good", "Afternoon"],0).
ans(["Good", "Night"],0).

answer([], []).
answer([H], List):- findall(ans(X,S), (ans(X,S), member(H, X)), List) , !.
answer([H|T], List):- answer([H], L1), answer([T], L2), append(L1, L2, List).
```

This predicate receives a list of atoms and should return the structures ans that match with the atoms in the list given.
Ex: answer(["Hello"],L) L = [ans(["Hello"], 0), ans(["Hello", "dear", "customer"], 0)]
But it only works for the first atom and I cant understand why. If the list has more than 1 atom it only works for the first one. 
Ex: answer(["Hi", "Hello"], L) L = [] and it should return the same output of the other example above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried taking off the cut in the the second instance of the predicate answer? (sry writting this on the answer section but i dont have enough karma to comment :/)

Comment: Yes I did try taking off the cut but without it the predicate never ends.

Comment: Oh yes you are right I tried your code in the interpreter and it really does an infinite answer.